# How to reduce multiple checks over a list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list which include type as a property, based on type I am filtering the objects and doing sum of another property in the same filtered list.

below is the example code I have tried?

```
 list: [
 {
    "type": "H",
    "amount": 101
  },
  {
    "type": "A",
    "amount": 10
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "amount": 10
  },
  {
    "type": "A",
    "amount": 100
  },
  {
    "type": "C",
    "amount": 10
  },
  {
    "type": "F",
    "amount": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "A",
    "amount": 4
  },
 {
    "type": "",
    "amount": 7
  },
  {
    "type": null,
    "amount": 3
  }
]


BigDecimal unknownSum = list.stream().filter(x -> (x.getType().isEmpty() || x.getType() == null)).map(x -> x.getAmount()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal aSum = list.stream().filter(x -> (x.getType().equals("A") || x.getType().equals("H"))).map(x -> x.getAmount()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal bSum = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getType().equals("B")).map(x -> x.getAmount()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal cSum = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getType().equals("C")).map(x -> x.getAmount()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal fSum = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getType().equals("F")).map(x -> x.getAmount()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal othSum = list.stream().filter(x -> !(x.getType().equals("A") || x.getType().equals("B") || x.getType().equals("C"))).map(x -> x.getAmount()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
   

 public class Account {
          private BigDecimal averageSum;
          private BigDecimal accountSum;
          private BigDecimal fixedSum;
          private BigDecimal totalSum;
          private BigDecimal othersSum;
          private BigDecimal unKnownSum;
   }

Account ac = new Account();

ac.setAverage(aSum);
ac.setAccountSum(bSum);
ac.setFixedSum(cSum);
ac.setTotalSum(fSum);
ac.setOthersSum(othSum);
ac.setUnKnownSum(unknownSum);
```

the above code is working fine, but I want to reduce no of iterations over the list for each check.
is there any way that I can use single iteration and pass different checks and set the different response for each property as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a map.

- Group by the type
- then use a [Collectors.mapping()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to get the amount
- then compute each sum using [Collectors.reducing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator))

I am using a record as the Property class as I understand it

Some Data

```
record Property(String getType, BigDecimal getAmount) {
}

List<Property> list = List.of(
          new Property("A", BigDecimal.valueOf(10)),
          new Property("C", BigDecimal.valueOf(20)),
          new Property("D", BigDecimal.valueOf(30)),
          new Property("F", BigDecimal.valueOf(40)),
          new Property("A", BigDecimal.valueOf(50)),
          new Property("D", BigDecimal.valueOf(60)),
          new Property("C", BigDecimal.valueOf(70)),
          new Property("F", BigDecimal.valueOf(80)));

Map<String, BigDecimal> sums = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Property::getType,
                Collectors.mapping(Property::getAmount, Collectors
                        .reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));

sums.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
A=60
C=90
D=90
F=120
```

Other sums can be computed from the map.

```
BigDecimal totalSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (BigDecimal bigd : sums.values()) {
    totalSum = totalSum.add(bigd);
}
System.out.println("Total sum = " + totalSum);
BigDecimal DCSums = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for( String type : "DC".split("")) {
       DCSums = DCSums.add(sums.get(type));
}

System.out.println("DCSums = " + DCSums);
```

prints

```
Total sum = 360
DCSums = 180
```

Comment: Very nice! `String type, BigDecimal amount` could be perhaps better names.

Comment: @menteith True.  But with a record, the field names and the getters are named the same and either can be used.  So I was taking the getter approach so that how I named them.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of taste, but I would prefer just a field name without get prefix.

Comment: @WJS thanks for the answer, I have updated the conditions, could you please consider those cases as well(unknownSum, othSum, aSum), in my case I don't need grouping of all the type's

Comment: You can compute other sums from the map by using specific keys (see update).  You can also filter out bad types like `null`. My answer was based on your previous version of the question so this is the best I can offer.

Comment: @menteith I think, the logical conclusion is that we should not answer questions tagged with `java` but not providing actual Java types (rather throwing some JSON or similar garbage at us). No guessing about the OP’s intended coding styles, just downvoting until the OP shows, how the actual Java classes look like…

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it at the moment because I don't have the underlying classes but this should give you a `Map<String, BigDecimal>`:

```
list.stream().collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getType(),
     Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getAmmount(), 
     Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.add)));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just iterating over the list and adding elements to the appropriate sum variable? A little old school without using Streams perhaps, but only iterates over the list once.

```
BigDecimal aSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal bSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal cSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal fSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

for (val x : list) {
    switch (x.getType()) {
        case "A":
        aSum = aSum.add(x.getAmount());
        break;

        case "B":
        bSum = bSum.add(x.getAmount());
        break;

        case "C":
        cSum = cSum.add(x.getAmount());
        break;

        case "F":
        fSum = fSum.add(x.getAmount());
        break;        
    }
}
```